# I am trying to connect from Oracle to other database like PostgreSQL using Heterogeneous Database connections

Tags: oracle, postgresql, dblink

The error I am getting is 
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from PG_LINK
28545. 0000 -  "error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent"

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on there.  "Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message" usually means a mis-configuration of ORACLE_HOME, preventing the failing process from locating the file the contains the text of error messages.  So I googled the underlying error code 'ORA-02063'.  (Suggest you do the same).  Most common causes of this error seem to be

This "catchall" error can happen if:

- The environment is not set correctly (e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not
  point to the unixODBC library directories, or ODBCSYSINI does not
  point to the to the directory containing the copy of odbc.ini where
  the target ODBC DSN is defined.)
- A 64-bit DG4ODBC library is being used with 32-bit ODBC libraries and vice versa.
- The SID specified in your DG4ODBC config is not running on the host
  specified in tnsnames.ora.

(reference https://www.easysoft.com/blog/ora-02063.html).

Also, for a more general walk-through of configuring a db link to a non-oracle database, see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/